# Ипользование коллайдера для моделей

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Я скачал модель дома с одного сайта. В доме есть комнаты, другие объекты и вообще в него можно зайти.

Вопрос: как использовать коллайдер так, чтобы имеющейся отверстия в доме остались проходимыми.

Comment: Руками, каждую стеночку

Answer (score 2):

При вставке модели есть 2 варианта генерирования колайдеров.

1. Сделать автоматический meshСollider который точно по контуру обрисует модель.
2. Самому вручную из стандартных Box, Sphere и т.д колайдеров сделать коллайдер для каждого элемента.
   Если деталь сложная или большая, и нет необходимости, как в вашем случае, точного позиционирования 2 способ лучше